# What is replacement or workaround for ActionNameSelectorAttribute in .net 6 /.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

My application with .net framework 4.8 is using ActionNameSelectorAttribute--> public override bool IsValidName, what is the replacement or workaround for this in .net 6 (core). I am my migrating my applicaiton to .net 6 and I could not find it ,

Below is the one used in old framework application:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultiBtnAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Value);
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
            controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = value;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I could not find `valueProvider` directly as mentioned above and `ControllerContext.RouteData` is null.

Please let me know if any other way it works with less code changes.

I tried `CompositeValueProvider` but it did not work.

Comment: In .NET 6/.NET Core, the ActionNameSelectorAttribute attribute has been removed, and there is no direct replacement for it.